# R unexpected behaviour

Tags: r, ubuntu

I have ubuntu 14.04.3 and installed R 3.2.2
I have the following script

```
t0 <- .100          # Natural Process Time (hr) - site busyness
mf <- 100000            # MTTF (hr)
mr <- 8             # MTTR (hr)

A <- mf/(mf+mr)         # Availability
tec <- t0/A         # Effective Process Time (failures only)
```

But when I paste it in R console it produces some werid output like

```
> t0 <- .100# Natural Process Time (hr) - site busyness
> mf <- 100000# MTTF (hr)
> mr <- 8# MTTR (hr)
> 
> A <- mf/(mf+mr)# Availability
> tec <- t0/A
t0/A              t0/AirPassengers  t0/Arith          t0/ARMAtoMA
t0/AIC            t0/Arg            t0/ARMAacf        t0/Axis
> tec <- t0/A
t0/A              t0/AirPassengers  t0/Arith          t0/ARMAtoMA
t0/AIC            t0/Arg            t0/ARMAacf        t0/Axis
> tec <- t0/A# Effective Process Time (failures only)
```

What might be the cause for these? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are copy/pasting some `\t` (tab buttons) on the R console.

Comment: Can you also suggest what brings out the names like AirPassengers and all?

Comment: @nicola is correct - what is happening is the auto-suggest type-ahead of the R interpreter. 
If you open the interpreter and type A then hit the tab key, you will see it suggests all of the above AirPassengers, Arith, etc.

Comment: Is it specific to R console or this general ubuntu behavior? How to turn it off?

Comment: Don't turn it off! Auto-suggest is so useful that working without would be awful. Just don't worry about that output. It doesn't have any effect or consequence whatsoever. If you really don't want to see it, just remove tabs from your file and use blank spaces instead.